# Refactoring code from every enum to containing struct

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums

I am trying to reduce boilerplate code. In the following example I am trying to refactor the static function from every extensions to the struct.

```
struct Namespace {
}

extension Namespace {

    enum UserDefaults: String {
        case Password = "password"
        case oldSavedLists = "savedLists"
        case isNotFirstLaunch
        case dbUpdateDateStatus
    }

    static func raw(_ id: UserDefaults) -> String {
        return id.rawValue
    }
}


extension Namespace {
    enum Database: String {
        case userUpdateStatus = "user_update_status"
        case dbUpdates = "db_updates"
    }

    static func raw(_ id: Database) -> String {
        return id.rawValue
    }
}
```

Is this possible somehow?
I tried using generics, but failed. Generics still are kind of strange to me..

Thanks!

EDIT:
How about something like this? The calling syntax would be more concise.

```
struct Namespace {
}

extension Namespace {

    struct UserDefaults {
        static let Password = "password"
        static let oldSavedLists = "savedLists"
        static let isNotFirstLaunch
        static let dbUpdateDateStatus
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you still have a question? The solution you've found yourself is the best way to do it IMO (feel free to add it as an answer rather than an edit to the question).

Comment: Well if there is faster option, I am glad to hear. Maybe lazy loading somehow? Otherwise yes I will add my idea as an answer

Comment: What do you mean by "faster option"? You mean performance-wise? The difference (if any) will be trivial. Unless you've identified this as a bottleneck, you shouldn't be deciding on approaches solely based on performance.

Comment: Yes performance wise. You are probably right, I won't matter.